# User Interface for Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gwt

I do not even know how to start to ask this question.  So here is my best effort.  Please guide me along.  I have always been interested in GAE.  Now I would like to develop an application that uses GAE.  But I am having trouble selecting the appropriate technology stack to use with GAE.  For example, should I use Python or Java in GAE?  Should I use GWT or some other tool to develop the end user interface (GUI).

Right now, I tend to favor using Python on the GAE.  But I don't know about the end user interface (GUI).  Is GWT the only option?

About my little application:
The application will allow the user to input information/photos about an inspection (common stuff) and create a record of the inspection.  Then the application will generated an inspection report (common format) of a selected record.

I hope this is enough to describe my dilemma.  Thanks,

Comment: Google App Engine lets you build web applications, you can use any technology on the frontend that you want. You could use Angular, Ember.js, HTML5 boilerplate, Bootstrap... Whatever you want!

Comment: Or you can say screw the web, I'm just going to have mobile apps as the frontend and GAE as the backend.

Comment: @ThomasOrozco you should made that comment an answer (before we close the question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

App Engine Python applications have built in support for [webapp2](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/) which itself inherently support [Django templates out of the box](http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/gettingstarted/templates.html?highlight=template). GWT is definitely not the only option.

As Thomas Orozco said in his answer, you can use a myriad of front end technologies. Although I've never tried it, if you wrote your app in Python I'm sure you could use Cheetah, Jinja2, or some other templating language.

Comment: I understand that anything can be used for the front-end.  I hope I don't blow this question too wide open.  So let me try to clarify/rephrase my question a little.  

If I were an apprentice working under a mentor (a wise and trusted counselor), what would he/she advise to use on this project?

I would like the end-user experience to be like working with a desktop application and less like access webpages on a website.

BTW, anyone know how I could find/locate a mentor to help me along with my project.

Comment: BTW, I could just develop my application as a Google Chrome Application (maybe?).  Only one or two users will be using this app.